# Angular6/Typescript - Mapping of Objects in Arrays in Arrays

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, mapping

We have 2 arrays **speisekarte** (10 objects) and **essensplan** (8 objects)

```
const speisekarte = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Kabeljaufilet', preis: 3.55, art: 'mit Fisch' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Spaghetti Bolognese', preis: 3.85, art: 'mit Fleisch' },

const essensplan = [
  { id: 1, essenProWoche: [11, 12] },
```

I want **essensplan** to call the ID's from **speisekarte** and print out the details of it. At the moment, my web page looks like this:

```
  - 1, 11, 12
```

How do implement the details by just using the ID's.

I already have a method for "EssenID" for the detail page of one object but I dont know, how to use it for this type of array.

```
/** GET essen by ID. Will 404 if id not found */
getEssen(id: number): Observable<Essen> {
  const url = `${this.speisekarteUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Essen>(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`fetched essen id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Essen>(`getEssen id=${id}`))
 );
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to call `this.http.get` for each `id` from `essenProWoche`?

Comment: No. I want the informations to be printed out by **essensplan**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop throw `essensplan` object then loop throw the list of `essenProWoche` and attach click event to get the selected object by `essenProWoche` list.

*template*

```
<p>List of  essensplan </p>
<div *ngFor="let i of essensplan"> 
  <div>essensplan : {{i.id}}</div>
   <button *ngFor="let id of i.essenProWoche" (click)="print(id)">Ptint Item {{id}} </button>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Selected Item</p>
  {{selectedItem | json}}
</div>
```

*component*

```
  speisekarte = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Kabeljaufilet', preis: 3.55, art: 'mit Fisch' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Spaghetti Bolognese', preis: 3.85, art: 'mit Fleisch' }
  ]

  essensplan = [
    { id: 1, essenProWoche: [11, 12] }
  ]


  selectedItem

  print(id: number) {
     this.selectedItem = this.speisekarte.find(i => i.id == id) 
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-36vre5)

if you want to show item name on the print button it's better to map the id to related object like this

*component*

```
  speisekarte = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Kabeljaufilet', preis: 3.55, art: 'mit Fisch' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Spaghetti Bolognese', preis: 3.85, art: 'mit Fleisch' }
  ];

  essensplan : {id:number,essenProWoche:any[]}[] = [
    { id: 1, essenProWoche: [11, 12] },
  ];


  selectedItem;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.essensplan.forEach(item => {
      item.essenProWoche = item.essenProWoche.map( id => {
        
        return  this.speisekarte.find(i => i.id == id) ;
      })
    })
  }
  print(item: number) {
     this.selectedItem = item;
  }
```

*template*

```
<p>List of  essensplan </p>
<div *ngFor="let i of essensplan"> 
  <div>essensplan : {{i.id}}</div>
   <button *ngFor="let item of i.essenProWoche" (click)="print(item)">Ptint Item => {{item.name}} </button>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Selected Item</p>
  {{selectedItem | json}}
</div>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lhpa6f)

happy coding

Comment: hey. im trying out your code, but it seems like if you click on a button, every button has the same outprint, Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Do you know, how I can Print the Name of the Objects of Speisekarte into the buttons, instead of the ID's

Comment: @Ascena  you can map each id in essenProWoche to each object in speisekarte

Comment: @Ascena I have update the answer to show maped item instead of id